# How can we identify comma in search string and accordingly fire query in MySQL?

Tags: php, android, mysql, sql

I am making a small city guide application in which I have two tables in the database:

```
country(country_code(pk),country_name)

city(city_id(pk), city_name, city_details, country_code(fk))
```

Now, if user searches for particular `city_name` or `country_name`, I can use `LIKE` operator as:

```
SELECT city_name,city_details,country_name FROM table city INNER JOIN country ON city.contry_code = country.country_code WHERE city_name LIKE "search_string";
```

But, what if user searches for comma separated values like if he searches for `'Ahmedabad,India'` instead of only `'Ahmedabad'`? Then what to do? plz help. I am using PHP and MySQL.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

@xyz i think you can do this in MYSQL itself using regular expression.

```
SELECT * FROM city INNER JOIN country ON
city.contry_code = country.country_code
WHERE CONCAT(city.city_name,", ", country.country_name) REGEXP  '^your search string'
```

here "^" will match beginning of the string. For more info about regular expression in MYSQL refer this [link](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/mysql/mysql-regexps.htm)

Answer (score 2):

If it is the only case {state,Country} as you provide the data, you can split the string using explode or another php function before run the query and can add filter like where state= {ahemdabad} && country= {India}.
It depends as per your requirement you can also use || condition instead &&.

Comment: I am very new to PHP. Can you link me to example for explode function?

Comment: explode is the function the split the string as per given delimiter and store the data in array. Please check http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php link for more info.

Answer (score 0):

Use `split(",")` from the `String` class. After that, you just need to search the result with your SQLite query.

EXAMPLE :

```
String[] results = etSearch.getText().toString().split(",");

for(int i = 0; i < results.length; i++)
   myDatabaseInstance.search(results[i]);
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution by @keshav-jha is pretty straight-forward and simple. It concatenates the city and country names and matches it against the regular expression. Looks good for only a particular input format of either: `Ahmadabad,India` (no-space after comma) OR `Ahmadabad, India` (a space after comma). So if the search query has to handle this space issue we can do away with `REGEXP` here and just use simple `like` statement in conjunction with `REPLACE` as:

### solution 1:

```
SELECT * FROM city INNER JOIN country ON
city.contry_code = country.country_code
WHERE CONCAT(city.city_name,",", country.country_name) like REPLACE(TRIM('your search string'),' ','');
```

You can choose to use REGEXP instead of LIKE but you'll have to find a way to remove all white-space characters in the string within the REGEXP expression itself. Because MySql uses Henry Spencer's implementation of regular expressions in conformance with POSIX 1003.2 which won't allow `free-spacing mode` using the `?x` at the beginning of the regular expression so you need to find another way to enforce free-spacing mode in your REGEXP OR you can use the original code by @keshav-jha with an added logical expression if you choose to use REGEXP for any reasons:

### solution 2:

```
SELECT * FROM city INNER JOIN country ON
city.contry_code = country.country_code
WHERE CONCAT(city.city_name,", ", country.country_name) REGEXP '^your search string' OR CONCAT(city.city_name,",", country.country_name) REGEXP '^your search string';
```